# Is there a generic way to find the length of any null-terminated string?

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I am writing my own Range class in c++17 to allow iterating over any range of integers, characters or elements in any container. I have already written constructors for containers, arrays and integers. Now I need a constructor that can take any string pointer type, assumed to be null-terminated, and initialize the `m_start` and `m_end` iterators from that.

This is what the constructor looks like:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr Range(T* p_string) noexcept :
    m_start{p_string},
    m_end{p_string + getLengthOfStringPointer(p_string)}
{}
```

I just need to implement the generic `getLengthOfStringPointer`, and it should work for both `const` and non-`const` characters of any type and size; `char16_t`, `wchar_t`, `char` and so on.

It's not that hard to do manually, but is there something like this in the standard library?

Edit: clarified that the constructor is not meant to handle the cases of integers, arrays or containers.

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! I looked up how `std::basic_string_view` does it, and it uses `std::char_traits<T>::length`. This function is constexpr since c++17, so the constructor can keep its constexpr specifier!

The code simply becomes:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr Range(T* p_string) noexcept :
    m_start{p_string},
    m_end{p_string + std::char_traits<T>::length(p_string)}
{}
```

`std::char_traits` on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits)